# Json parsing, dictionary value print

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, iphone

I want to get the whatsapp number from JSON data which is in format as below

**Json:**" extra_values":"{\"whatsapp\":\"1234567890\",\"call\":\"+1234567890\"}"

```
    social_dict=[shop_info valueForKey:@"extra_values"];
    NSLog(@"%@",social_dict);//it_prints : {"whatsapp":"1234567890","call":"+1234567890"}


    NSLog(@"%@",[social_dict objectForKey:@"call"]);

    NSLog(@"%@",[social_dict objectForKey:@"whatsapp"]);
```

I am having problem in printing the whatsapp value.

> **Error:**  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60400028bd10'

Comment: it prints {"whatsapp":"1234567890","call":"+1234567890"} so i think it means it is in dictionary.

Comment: @Sunnymori You should convert Json string to `NSDictionary` value berofe using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
NSString *social_str = [shop_info valueForKey:@"extra_values"];

NSError *jsonError;
NSData *objectData = [social_str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary * social_dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                      options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                        error:&jsonError];
```

You are getting JSON string for `extra_values` so you have to convert it to `NSDictionary` by this

Comment: Thank you so much bro @vp2698

Comment: Welcome bro @Sunnymori

Comment: Do not use `valueForKey:` unless you have a clearly understood need to use key-value coding. Use `objectForKey:`. Better yet, use modern syntax: `NSString *social_str = shop_info[@"extra_values"];`